# SQL compare two tables and get the record which has the most recent date

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

There are 2 tables. Table a and b. A contains msisdn, firstname, secondname, lastname, regdate(registration data). Table b also has the same fields. msisdn X is in table A and table B with two different regdate's. i need to query both the tables and get the result which has the recent regdate.

like msisdn X regdate in table A is 01/APR/2016 and X regdate in table B is 01/AUG/2016, when i query i should get the result of X from B because that has the most recent regdate.

thanks

Comment: I think you should be more specific what "the result" means. Did you want the entire row from the table with the greatest regdate?

Comment: yeah, the entire row from the table with the latest regdate.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT msisdn, max(regdate)
FROM (SELECT msisdn, regdate
FROM tablea
UNION
SELECT msisdn, regdate
FROM tableb)
group by msisdn;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the complete record:

```
select ab.*
from (select ab.*,
             row_number() over (partition by msisdn order by regdate desc) as seqnum
      from ((select a.*
             from tablea a
            ) union all
            (select b.*
             from tableb b
            )
           ) ab
     ) ab
where seqnum = 1;
```